# How to have recipients' email addresses in different colors in Gmail like the previous version?

Tags: gmail

In old style of Gmail, a conversation (grouped messages) is displayed using different color for different recipients/senders.

With the new appearance, that has been removed. This gives me find quite a lot of difficulties when mailing with multiple users at the same time.

The new interface put in the photo of the sender for each message. But that is not very useful for me when I look back my messages to seek for the ones that has recipient to be Ms ABC for example. With the old interface, I just look for the color; now, I have to read wrong-designed `gray text`.

If you know how to turn this on back, please share.

The Old
[image: Old Gmail conversation]

The New (the different color rectangles should be color by Gmail)
[image: New Gmail conversation]

Comment: They added user photos instead.

Comment: Unless you wish to do this on a local email client, its likely not possible without Google providing the option. And unless you wish to do this with a local email client, it belongs on webapps.SE and will be migrated there (i.e. Tell us, do you want yo do this with a local email client - a program on your computer rather than the webmail interface?).

Comment: @Bob I just want to stay with web mail. Local email client will keep my mail locally to a PC which I don't prefer at all. Thank you anyway Bob!

Comment: @grawity But just the photo of the sender which is not very useful for me when I look back my messages to seek for the mails which has recipient to be Ms ABC for example. Before, I look for the color; now, I have to read gray text.

Comment: IMAP is designed to allow you to use a local client while keeping the emails on the server, so you can still view it from other locations and even the web interface if that's your worry.

Comment: @Bob Yeah I've used IMAP/POP3 before but for now I just want a browser to check my mail and to me web mail is best suited

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed in the comments, this is not possible. Google has changed its interface. It does that often and you cannot rollback to the old interface/any feature of the old interface.